# IPhone Bluetooth Connectivity to external hardware device over ATCommand or any other way

Tags: ios, bluetooth, obd-ii

I am working on bluetooth connectivity As I have to connect one hardware device (**Like OBDii**) but I don't know, how it is possible.

Hardware device(Which is attached to the vehicle) will send **ATCommand** and we need to have interpreted that command and device will display the full report to user related to that vehicle.

I quite aware that it is possible using android device but not sure about iphone. How it works and which framework will use for the same?

What specification/profile is required for that bluetooth hardware device ?

is that possible to communication with that ELD hardware device ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to connect your Device via Bluetooth to the OBD.
[Apple Developer Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/bluetooth/)

When you have created the connection with another device (like obd) you can send and receive message (like Android i think).

The AT commands are for talk with the ELM327 and configure it:

> AT SP 0 //Set protocol to AUTO
>
> AT Z //Reset ELM and show version
>
> etc etc

But for talk to the car you must use PIDs that are different to AT commands:

> 01 0C  //Speed or rpm don't remember
>
> 01 0D //Speed or rpm
>
> 01 51 //Type of fuel
>
> 03 00 //show trouble code
>
> Where 01 is Mode 1 (show real time data) and 03 is mode 3 (show
>   pending trouble code)

[Pids and mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#Mode_01)

Comment: Actually, there is not car but we need to communicate between truck or something like heavy vehicle. OBD device will not be similar like we used to see in the car. so I have confusion how it supposed to be connect and communication happened with it. We don't have that hardware device yet the moment but hardware specification document is there.

Comment: in Italy i see some site that have some adapter for Truck that convert truck port to OBD port.
Something like that?

Comment: Yes, Similar like that But Concern is how the communication happened over Bluetooth from ios device to that ELD hardware device ? When we need to use command and because that hardware device is queryable as well. so when we have to query the device?

Comment: note that this is a different from your initial post.
Edit your post and make it more clear.

Did you try with some terminal connected with this ELD for check if pids are same to OBD?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, you will have to use a Bluetooth 4.0 compliant OBD2 adapter, as iOS does not support the serial Bluetooth 3 profile. The proper framework to use is `CoreBluetooth`, which is a pretty straightforward implementation of the Bluetooth 4.0 spec.